# React with Typescript EventHandler type checking problem (onClick)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have been practicing React with Typescript these days.

I have PropsType as below

```
export type PropType = {
  ingredientAdded: (type: keyof IngredientType) => void;
}
```

and

```
const buildControl: React.FunctionComponent<PropType> = (props) => (
  <div className={classes.BuildControl}>
    <div className={classes.Label}>{props.label}</div>
    <button className={classes.Less}>Less</button>
    <button className={classes.More} onClick={props.ingredientAdded as any}>More</button>
  </div>
);
```

as body.

The problem here is I couldn't pass `onClick={props.ingredientAdded}` without casting to any.

when I look onClick type, it gives me

```
onClick?: MouseEventHandler<T>;
type MouseEventHandler<T = Element> = EventHandler<MouseEvent<T>>;
```

which seems that `ingredientAdded: (type: keyof IngredientType) => void;` function type is not valid for onClick.

However it works.

My question is what is the correct way of type checking here instead of casting to **any**

**Edit**

parent component passes the function.

```
type PropsType = {
  ingredientAdded(type: keyof IngredientType): void;
  ingredientRemoved(type: keyof IngredientType): void;
}

const controls: { label: string, type: keyof IngredientType }[] = [
  { label: 'Salad', type: 'salad' },
  { label: 'Bacon', type: 'bacon' },
  { label: 'Cheese', type: 'cheese' },
  { label: 'Meat', type: 'meat' },
];

const buildControls: React.FunctionComponent<PropsType> = (props) => (
  <div className={classes.BuildControls}>
    {controls.map(ctrl => (
      <BuildControl
        ingredientAdded={() => props.ingredientAdded(ctrl.type)}
        ingredientRemoved={() => props.ingredientRemoved(ctrl.type)}
        key={ctrl.label} label={ctrl.label} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default buildControls;
```

Comment: The question is, 1) does `props.ingredientAdded` need the click event object 2) how does it get its `type` argument?

Comment: answer 1) does not need click event handler. type argument is passed from parent compoenent. I will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

Please try wrapping `props.ingredientAdded` in a function.

## Without click event

```js
const buildControl: React.FunctionComponent<PropType> = (props) => (
  <div className={classes.BuildControl}>
    <div className={classes.Label}>{props.label}</div>
    <button className={classes.Less}>Less</button>
    <button className={classes.More} onClick={() => { props.ingredientAdded() }}>More</button>
  </div>
);
```

## With click event

```js
const buildControl: React.FunctionComponent<PropType> = (props) => (
  <div className={classes.BuildControl}>
    <div className={classes.Label}>{props.label}</div>
    <button className={classes.Less}>Less</button>
    <button className={classes.More} onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent) => { props.ingredientAdded(event) }}>More</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: `props.ingredientAdded()` function has type parameter which is not included in your example and also it is not available in child component. so function is needed to be referenced.

Comment: I don't think referring the function that way will play well in React with TypeScript but I’m not an expert.

Comment: My gut feeling is you might need to refactor your code to fit in this paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `onClick` on React expects that you're passing a function with a single argument that is a Mouse Event.

You could solve it two ways:

1. Wrap `onClick` with an arrow function:

```js
  // ...
  onClick={ (event) => { props.ingredientAdded(type) } }
```

2. **(Best way!)** Do this logic on a sub-component for your button, this way your event handler wouldn't explicit know the dependency of `ingredientAdded`:

```js
interface IngredientType {
  type: string;
}

export type PropType = {
  handler: (type: keyof IngredientType) => void;
  type: keyof IngredientType;
};

const MoreButton: React.FunctionComponent<PropType> = props => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.handler(props.type);
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>More</button>;
};

const MainComponent = ({ingredientAdded, type}) => {
  return <MoreButton handler={ingredientAdded} type={type} />
}
```

[Check the example for the second way.](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-nobel-kdxbd)

Comment: for the first approach, type is available here. It is passed from parent component. For the second approach, I know there are other ways of doing this but I dont want to change the behaviour of the component. I just couldn't understand why there is no types definition for working behavior

Comment: I understand. Usually TypeScript and type definitions helps us to detect ways we could improve our code, that's why I proposed the second solution.